# How to stop pytube python app from not responding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pytube

## Problem

My problem is that I am creating an app using PyTube and Tkinter. But when I start the download after inserting the link and output directory it not responds and this is bad because I have a progress bar and when it not responds the progress bar stops and ends up at zero when the not responding goes away.

## Not Responding:

[image]

## After Not Responding:

[image]

## What I have tried

I tried using the `time` module and doing `time.sleep(1)` but that didn't work so I removed it

## Code

```
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import pytube
import requests
import app


def download_video(download_entry, download_path_entry, file_name_entry, progress_bar, progress_label):
    url = "https://yamiatem.github.io/YTDownloader/"
    timeout = 5

    link = download_entry.get()
    out_dir = download_path_entry.get()
    file_name = file_name_entry.get()

    try:
        request = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout) as exception:
        showerror("Error", "You are not connected to the internet")
        return

    try:
        yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
    except:
        showerror("Error", " YouTube video link is invalid")
        return

    video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, mime_type="video/mp4", file_extension="mp4").first()

    def progress_check(chunk, file_handle, bytes_remaining):
        percent = round((float(bytes_remaining) / float(video.filesize)) * float(100))

        progress_bar['value'] = percent
        progress_label.configure(text=str(percent) + "%")

        app.root.update_idletasks()

    yt.register_on_progress_callback(progress_check)

    video.download(output_path=out_dir, filename=file_name)
```

### So How does one stop PyTube and Tkinter app from not responding

## Thanks in advance!

Comment: seems to me that download process blocks `mainloop` so You could try putting download stuff in a different thread

Comment: Not really sure if it will help but try changing `app.root.update_idletasks()` to `app.root.update()`. It might solve your problem.

Comment: @TheLizzard Yup that did it works now thank you if you would like you can upload it as an answer and I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while you are downloading the video the `tkinter` window isn't being updated. That is why Windows is saying that it is unresponsive. You tried fixing that with `app.root.update_idletasks()` but `.update_idletasks()` doesn't handle some of the events so Windows will assumes the program is unresponsive. If you change `.update_idletasks()` to `.update()`, it will handle all events and the window will stop being unresponsive.

The problem with this approach is that if `pytube` uses threading, it can crash `tkinter`. I don't know how `pytube` works internally. That is why @Matiiss suggested putting the downloader in another thread that updates a global variable. That is the safer approach but it takes a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use threading module to run this process in background.
here is an example to use thread

```
def func_thread(your_Arguments):
    from threading import Thread
    th=Thread(target=labmda: yourfunction(arguments...))
    th.setDaomon(True)
    th.start()
```